# How to filter elements in Wordpress Using JS / onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a method pretty much exactly like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp) from w3 schools to filter through elements in divs. I'm currently unable to add this working script into my Aurora Wordpress site. However, Due to the stripping of the onclick() function. Does anybody have a workaround to be able to filter elements like this? Maybe without using this function or getting around that blocking? I've read about using shortcodes but most of those examples were href links as opposed to input buttons/hopefully a drop-down select sometime in the future and I was unsuccessful in trying to implement them into my solution. Here's a small example of usage (the full JS code is on the page linked at the top of this question).

```
<input type="radio" onclick="filterSelection('all')" name="category" checked>Show all<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="filterSelection('1')" name="category"> Option 1
<input type="radio" onclick="filterSelection('2')" name="category"> Option 2
```

etc

Comment: did you created any html for filter and elment section?

Comment: @Balwant it's essentially the same as the w3schools example I linked to! I can't post the exact code here because there's some personal information information.

Comment: no its not necessary to create the exact html you can create your own. here
 are some example : https://codepen.io/NickyCDK/pen/lhaiz,   https://codepen.io/terf/post/jquery-filter-divs, https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/Eoydz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
              <button class="button" data-filter=".<?php echo $term_tech->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term_tech->name; ?>(<?php echo $term_tech->count; ?>)</button>
             <?php

      $port = array(

      'posts_per_page'   => -1,

      'orderby' => 'menu_order',

      'order' => 'ASC',

      'post_type' => 'portfolio',

      'post_status' => 'publish'

      );







      $portfolioget = get_posts($port);



      foreach ($portfolioget as $portfoliopost){



       echo '<div class="element-item '.implode(" ",get_video_temrs($portfoliopost->ID)).'" data-category="transition">';
      .......code.........
          <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(window).on('load',function ($) {

//jQuery(".element-item").css('max-height','265px');
    // jQuery(".portfolio-img img").css('min-height','184px');
    //jQuery(".portfolio-img img").addClass('minHightImg');

    jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload({

    effect : "fadeIn",
    effectspeed: 2000

}); 



    var $grid = jQuery('.grid').isotope({

        itemSelector: '.element-item',

        layoutMode: 'fitRows',

        getSortData: {

            name: '.name',

            symbol: '.symbol',

            number: '.number parseInt',

            category: '[data-category]',

            weight: function (itemElem) {

                var weight = jQuery(itemElem).find('.weight').text();

                return parseFloat(weight.replace(/[\(\)]/g, ''));

            }

        }

    });

    var filterFns = {

        // show if number is greater than 50

        numberGreaterThan50: function () {

            var number = jQuery(this).find('.number').text();

            return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;

        },

        // show if name ends with -ium

        ium: function () {

            var name = jQuery(this).find('.name').text();

            return name.match(/ium$/);

        }

    };

    jQuery('#filters').on('click', 'button', function () {

        var filterValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');

        // use filterFn if matches value

        filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;

        $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});

    });

    jQuery('#filters_industries').on('click', 'button', function () {

        var filterValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');

        // use filterFn if matches value

        filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;

        $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});

    });

    jQuery('#sorts').on('click', 'button', function () {

        var sortByValue = jQuery(this).attr('data-sort-by');

        $grid.isotope({sortBy: sortByValue});

    });

    jQuery('.button-group').each(function (i, buttonGroup) {

        var $buttonGroup = jQuery(buttonGroup);

        $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function () {

            $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');

            jQuery(this).addClass('is-checked');

        });

    });


});
```